# How to put external text file in Eclipse view

Tags: java, eclipse

[eclipse screenshot http://02500.net/qq.png](http://02500.net/qq.png)

Hello guys, I wonder how can I put my external text file in eclipse view. few months ago I put that eclipse view, so I could edit my text file in eclipse easily. but I bought new computer I forgot how I did it. so these days I open new window and find my text file and then edit, it's so inconvenient. please save my time! thanks.

Comment: Drag and drop :D. Give me a Chocolate now :P

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Oh thank you. how can I choose your comment to answer? I didn't know that.

Comment: Do the same for existing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag your file from a folder and drop it in IDE window, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

By Drag Drop you can Copy your file.So applying any changes from eclipse won't affect your ***original one***.

But while doing drag and drop you can select `Link to Files` so now you can change file of drive from eclipse.

[image]